# How to count the number of a specific value within a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have the 2D array

```
X X X O O O 
O O O O O O 
O O O O O O 
X X X X O O 
O O O O O O 
O O O O O O
```

I want to count the number of X's recurring within the 2D array. In this case it should be 7. I want to return a true/false boolean value. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You iterate over the array and increment a counter each time you find the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use Lambda expression for this. But, for you might be easier to understand iterating over your 2D array and collect the count in a map.

```
public class CountDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] matrix = { 
                { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O' }, 
                { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
                { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
                { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O' }, 
                { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' }, 
                { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' }};

        Map<Character, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<>();
        for (char[] characters : matrix) {
            for (char character : characters) {
                Integer count = charCount.get(character);
                if (count == null) {
                    charCount.put(character, 1);
                } else {
                    charCount.put(character, ++count);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Character count");
        System.out.println("X's: " + charCount.get('X'));
        System.out.println("O's: " + charCount.get('O'));
    }
}
```

The output of this program is

```
Character count
X's: 7
O's: 29
```

The explanation of the code:

The outer for-loop iterates over each array of characters while the inner loop iterates over the characters in the current array.

Once you have a character, you will "get" the current (count) value for the given key (character). If no matched character is found, the `get()` function will return null. In that case, you found the first instance of that character; so  you just enter the value of "1" for the count and save it in the map. Otherwise, you increment the current count and you **put** back the updated count in the map.

Once you finish iterating over the matrix, you are ready to display the stats. Since I knew this example was just 'X' and 'O', I just called the `get()` directly. When you don't know the contents of the map, the correct solution is to iterate over the map's entries and get whatever is there. So, the `System.out` statements in the code above should be replaced with the following code snippet:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> iter = charCount.entrySet().iterator();
        
System.out.println("Character count");
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Entry<Character, Integer> entry = iter.next();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "'s: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

If you were to change your character matrix as follows

```
        char[][] matrix = { 
                { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'E', 'O' }, 
                { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
                { 'E', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
                { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'E', 'O' }, 
                { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' }, 
                { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'E', 'O' }};
```

The output of the program using the `EntrySet` solution will be as follows

```
Character count
E's: 4
X's: 7
O's: 25
```

Answer (score 1):

The most basic solution would be, to have a Methode, that needs a 2D-Array and the value that you are expecting. Then you iterate through the array using two for-loops. Every time you find an x, you add plus one onto an int variable. After you iterated through the 2D-Array, you compare that counter with the expected value and return a true if the numbers are the same and a false if this is not the case.
Something like this:

```
public boolean countX (char[][] array, int expectation){
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                if(array[i][j] == 'x'){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter == expectation;
    }
```